# Python asyncio server hanging when attempting to reuse connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

QUESTION: Recreating the connection each time works, creating it once and attempting to reuse leads to program hang after first exchange of data. Why, and how to reuse the connection?

I am attempting to create a TCP Socket Client, TCP WebSocket Client and subsequently TCP Socket Server and TCP WebSocket Server. The TCP Client sends data to the TCP Socket Server. The TCP Socket Server sends the data to a Queue. The WebSocket Server retrieves the data from the Queue and sends it to the WebSocket Client. It basically looks like this:

```
TCP Socket Client ---data---> TCP Socket Server ---data---> Queue ---data---> TCP WebSocket Server ---data---> TCP WebSocket Client
```

I have the following file structure with and the code within:

```
---TCP_Socket_Client.py
---TCP_WebSocket_Client.py
---main.py
```

TCP_Socket_Client.py: - establishes a connection with the TCP Socket Server and by user input sends `data` to TCP Socket Server. (Here is the main problem I am asking about - take note of this file and mainly, notice that the connection is being generated once.)

```
import asyncio
import json


async def tcp_client():
    _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
            '127.0.0.1', 16001)
    while True:
        data: str = input("Write JSON data: ")
        print(f"Sending JSON data: {data}")
        data_json: str = json.dumps(data)
        writer.write(data_json.encode())
        await writer.drain()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(tcp_client())
```

TCP_WebSocket_Client.py: - Establishes a websocket connection to the TCP WebSocket Server and receives the data that was sent from that server. It then displays the data on the screen.

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def client():
    uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:16000/"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Client received data: {data}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(client())
```

main.py: - Holds the code for the TCP Socket Server and the TCP WebSocket Server.

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

pub_sub_Queue: asyncio.Queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def server_to_client(websocket):
    while True:
        print(f"Point 5: Websocket server awaits data from QUEUE.")
        data = await pub_sub_Queue.get()
        print(f"Point 6: Websocket server received data {data} from QUEUE.")
        await websocket.send(data)
        print(f"Pont 7: Websocket server sent data to client.")


async def server_to_TCP(reader, writer):
    while True:
        print("Point 2: Server awaits data from TCP server")
        data: bytes = await reader.read(1024)
        if data:
            data_dict: dict = json.loads(data.decode())
            print(f"Point 3: Server received {data_dict} from TCP server.")
            await pub_sub_Queue.put(data)
            print("Point 4: Server sent data to QUEUE.")


async def main():
    server_1 = await asyncio.start_server(server_to_TCP, '127.0.0.1', 16001)
    async with await websockets.serve(server_to_client, "127.0.0.1", 16000), server_1:
        print("Point 1: Starting servers.")
        await asyncio.gather(server_1.serve_forever())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

After running the code, the algorithm works only the first time and then it hangs:

```
1. All aspects start without a problem.
2. Sending a message from TCP Client Server to TCP Socket server works.
3. Queue transition works.
4. WebSocket Server sends message to WebSocket client.

Afterwards, attempting to send a message to the TCP Socket Server from the TCP Socket Client will work, but the message will not be accepted by the TCP Socket Server.

5. Sending a message from TCP Client Server to TCP Socket server works.
6. Queue transition does NOT work!
7. HANG!
```

Here is what print debugging returns:

```
Starting the servers:
Point 1: Starting servers.
Point 2: Server awaits data from TCP server
Point 5: Websocket server awaits data from QUEUE.

Sending data from TCP Socket Server:
Point 3: Server received {"data":1} from TCP server.
Point 4: Server sent data to QUEUE.
Point 2: Server awaits data from TCP server
Point 6: Websocket server received data b'"{\\"data\\":1}"' from QUEUE.
Pont 7: Websocket server sent data to client.
Point 5: Websocket server awaits data from QUEUE.
```

At this point, both servers are expecting new data. One from Queue and another from TCP Socket Client. We can send data from the TCP Socket Client, but nothing will happen. There are no errors, nor anything, it just hangs.

Now, the interesting part. If we take a look the TCP Socket Client, we can notice that we create the connection outside of the `while True` loop and attempt to reuse it. This does NOT work. Creating the connection inside the `while True` makes the program work as expected.

TLDR: Recreating the connection each time works, creating it once and attempting to reuse leads to program hang after first exchange of data. Why, and how to reuse the connection?

```
 async def tcp_client():
    _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 16001) # DOES NOT WORK, PROGRAM HANGS
    while True:
        data: str = input("Write JSON data: ")
        print(f"Sending JSON data: {data}")
        data_json: str = json.dumps(data)
        writer.write(data_json.encode())
        await writer.drain()

 async def tcp_client():
    while True:
        _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
            '127.0.0.1', 16001) #WORKS. NO HANGING.
        data: str = input("Write JSON data: ")
        print(f"Sending JSON data: {data}")
        data_json: str = json.dumps(data)
        writer.write(data_json.encode())
        await writer.drain()
```